# Drawing 2 UIImage merged with different UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I've been trying to create a `for` loop which take `UILabel.text` and merge it into an `UIImage` then save it into an instance and then when getting into the `for` loop second time it would save the result in different instance.

The problem that I'm facing is that it is saving the first `UIImage` but with low quality and skipping the second one. I've even tried to do the `UIImage` saving code in a button action but still didn't work.

```
-(void)CreateTheImage{

    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SquareBackground.jpg"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imgView.bounds.size);
    int Counter = 0;

    for (UIView * view in [_imgView subviews]){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSString *txt1 = @"Test";
    NSString *txt2 = @"Worked Well";

    [array addObject:txt1];
    [array addObject:txt2];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%i",[array count]);
    NSLog(@"Before the loop");

    for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {

        NSLog(@"Entered the loop");
        NSLog(@"x = %i",x);

        lbl.text = [array objectAtIndex:x];
        NSLog(@"lbl.text = %@",[array objectAtIndex:x]);

        lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(20,112.5, 260, 75)];

        [_imgView addSubview:lbl];
        [_imgView bringSubviewToFront:lbl];
        [_imgView setImage:img];
        [_imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        Counter = x+1;
        NSLog(@"counter = %i",Counter);
        switch (Counter) {
            case 1:

                NSLog(@"swintch case 1");
                newImage1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                break;

            case 2:

                NSLog(@"swintch case 2");
                newImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        NSLog(@"after switch");

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    }

    //To save the picture in the album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage1, nil, nil, nil);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage2, nil, nil, nil);

    NSLog(@"After the loop");



}
```

Also when I run this method on my iPhone it gives me a warning which is

> CreatingVideo[334] : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Duncan C for helping me find the answer and correct the code to work perfectly now

```
-(void)CreateTheImage{

    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SquareBackground.jpg"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(320, 320), NO, 0.0f);

    int Counter = 0;


    NSString *txt1 = @"Test";
    NSString *txt2 = @"Worked Well";

    [array addObject:txt1];
    [array addObject:txt2];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%i",[array count]);
    NSLog(@"Before the loop");

    for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {

        for (UIView * view in [_imgView subviews]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

        NSLog(@"Entered the loop");
        NSLog(@"x = %i",x);

        lbl.text = [array objectAtIndex:x];
        NSLog(@"lbl.text = %@",[array objectAtIndex:x]);

        lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25];
        [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(20,122.5, 280, 75)];

        [_imgView addSubview:lbl];
        [_imgView bringSubviewToFront:lbl];
        [_imgView setImage:img];
        [_imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];


        Counter = x+1;
        NSLog(@"counter = %i",Counter);


        switch (Counter) {
            case 1:

                newImage1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                NSLog(@"swintch case 1");

                break;

            case 2:

                NSLog(@"swintch case 2");
                newImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        NSLog(@"after switch");



    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //To save the picture in the album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage1, nil, nil, nil);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage2, nil, nil, nil);

    NSLog(@"After the loop");



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense. You have a for loop that runs through an array, adds images to an image view, captures 1 of 2 images from the current off-screnen context, and then ends the image context after the first pass through the array. On the second pass, the context doesn't exist any more, so the second end context call will fail.

Move the end context outside of your for loop. That should fix your warning.

Even then, I'm not sure if it will work to remove subviews from an image view, add new views, an render the content to a graphics context, all without  returning. UIKit view drawing usually queues changes to the UI until your code returns, then renders it on the next pass through the event loop.

Comment: Thanks you so much worked perfectly with the saving but it is still not saving in a good quality

Comment: You should probably be using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and passing in the device scale. On a retina device the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext method will downsample your image to non-retina and it won't look as good.